# Monogame/XNA Collision Detection Issue

Tags: monogame, game-development

I am having some trouble with my collision/movement code and I was hoping for some help. I am new to XNA so excuse me if this is obvious.

My collision and movement code is currently on the scene for the sake of testing and it works perfectly when I check it against just one object (in this case, Player2). However, if I iterate through a list of objects, the collision/movement code stops working and I just move at a fast speed and through objects.

For example, the following code doesn't work:

```
foreach(Entity e in Entities)
    PlayerMove(Player.Velocity, e);
```

I have attached the TestScene code and if any other code is needed for clarification just let me know, thought I think most of the other code (Input, rendering, etc) is working as intended.

```
public class TestScene : Scene
{
    public Player Player;
    public Player Player2;

    public TestScene()
    {
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        Player = new Player(80, 80, 8, 16, "red");
        Player2= new Player(240, 80, 8, 16, "blue");

        Player2.ChangeControls(Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.RightShift);
    
        Entities.Add(Player, Player2);
    }

    public void PlayerMove(Vector2 velocity, Entity e)
    {
            if(velocity.X != 0 || velocity.Y != 0)
            {
                if(Collision.Check(e, new RectangleF(Player.X + velocity.X, Player.Y, Player.Width, Player.Height)))
                {
                    while(!Collision.Check(e, new RectangleF(Player.X + Math.Sign(velocity.X), Player.Y, Player.Width, Player.Height)))
                        Player.X += Math.Sign(velocity.X);
                }
                else
                    Player.X += (int)velocity.X;

                if(Collision.Check(e, new RectangleF(Player.X, Player.Y + velocity.Y, Player.Width, Player.Height)))
                {
                    while(!Collision.Check(e, new RectangleF(Player.X, Player.Y + Math.Sign(velocity.Y), Player.Width, Player.Height)))
                        Player.Y += Math.Sign(velocity.Y);
                }
                else
                    Player.Y += (int)velocity.Y;
            }
        }

    public override void Update()
    {

        Player.Direction = Vector2.Zero;

        if(Input.Pressed(Player.KUp) || Input.Pressed(Player.KDown))
        {
            Player.Direction.Y = Input.AxisCheck(Player.KUp, Player.KDown);
        }

        if(Input.Pressed(Player.KLeft) || Input.Pressed(Player.KRight))
        {
            Player.Direction.X = Input.AxisCheck(Player.KLeft, Player.KRight);
        }

        Player.Velocity = Player.MoveSpeed * Core.DeltaTime * Player.Direction;

        PlayerMove(Player.Velocity, Player2);

        Player.X = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(Player.X, 0, (Game1.Width) - Player.Collider.Width);
        Player.Y = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(Player.Y, 0, (Game1.Height) - Player.Collider.Height);
    
        base.Update();
    } 

    public override void Render()
    {
        base.Render();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in this part:

```
else
    Player.X += (int)velocity.X;
```

because you advance your player on each check within the loop. You should split parts of collision checking and movement so that you check multiple times, but move player only once.

Answer (score 0):

The player object should contain all of the code needed for that specific object.

Following the OOP principal of encapsulation, all class variables should be made private unless there is a compelling reason otherwise.  This makes debugging much easier and minimizes duplicate code.

All of the `Player.` lines are moved to the Player object all the while minimizing typing.

Avoid the `static` keyword unless it is game-wide ( it persists in memory throughout the application lifetime: score, high-score, lives, inventory, object state across levels/scenes [temporarily saved from local variables and restored after transition]), or required for all of the object instances to share(as in the "Space Invaders" movement direction, or win condition check across all objects, think puzzle pieces.)

Avoid naming instances of classes the same as the class. It is unclear from the code given whether the variables are static or not.

The Game1/Scene class should call an Update method for each player object(not needed if it is already an attached entity in monogame.extended, since it is done for you).
You are welcome to create additional public methods in `Player` and call them yourself:
The calls from the Scene/Game1(renaming Player to Player1):
public override void Update() //copied from question, not sure where the GameTime parameter went
{
Player1.Move(); // pass anything needed(like Input if not static)
Player2.Move();
Player1.Collide(Player2); // pass anything else as needed
Player2.Collide(Player1);
base.Update();
}

If you want to know who ran into whom, player1 will always win the tie. Order matters.

---

As far as I can tell, I am not sure if `static`s are involved, the code:

```
foreach(Entity e in Entities)
    PlayerMove(Player.Velocity, e);
```

causes `PlayerMove` to be called with player one's velocity twice; Hence the speedup.

---

The line:
`Player.Velocity = Player.MoveSpeed * Core.DeltaTime * Player.Direction;`
The `(int)X` and `(int)Y`  scales the Core.DeltaTime * direction to (1,0) * MoveSpeed. Therefore delta time running speed is ignored.

X and Y need to be float values. The simple solution is to use a `Vector2` for position. This enables the use of: `Position += Velocity;`The only time `(int)` comes into play is for the `Collision` rectangle, a separate, but related object,
Both X and Y need to be floats for this equation to be effective(hence the Vector2 type). Fractional pixels are rendered properly by Monogame.